# Extend a rational number field $\mathbb{Q}$ by using a transcendental number?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, transcendental-numbers

Here denoting a set of real transcendental numbers $\mathbb{T}$, what can we then say about the structure
$$
\mathbb{Q}(t) = \left\{\, \sum_{k=0}^{+ \infty} a_k t^k\mathrel{}\middle|\mathrel{} a_k \in \mathbb{Q} \,\right\},
\quad \text{for some } t \in \mathbb{T}.
$$

Now it is not a ring, is it? What do we have to add to make it a ring (or a field)?
Is $\mathbb{Q} \cup \mathbb{T}$ a ring (or a field)?

Comment: I'm siding with Mike's answer and thinking this as the ring of formal power series (treating $t$ as a variable). If you start thinking about plugging in a real number in place of $t$, then you need to worry about convergence. And it is easy to produce sequences of rational numbers $(a_k)_{k\ge0}$ such that the series has radius of convergence zero, and thus won't converge at $t$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, what you write as $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ is a ring - it's the ring of formal power series with rational coefficients. Usually it's denoted $\mathbb{Q}[[t]]$.

Any element of the form $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k t^k$$ is invertible if and only if $a_k \neq 0$; if $a_0=0, a_1 \neq 0$, the inverse will take the form $$\sum_{k=-1}^\infty b_k t^k$$ This justifies the fact that the field of fractions of $\mathbb{Q}[[t]]$ (denoted $\mathbb{Q}((t))$) is the ring of formal Laurent series:

$$\sum_{k=-n}^\infty a_k t^k$$ for some integer $n$.

---

**EDIT**: I'm no longer satisfied with this answer. What I've written above is just fine if you consider $\mathbb{Q}[[t]]$ just as a ring of formal power series, not trying to *evaluate* any element of it (by replacing $t$ by the relevant transcendental number). However, many of these series will not converge - pick, say, $a_k = \pm 1$ for something that goes to $\pm \infty$, or $a_k = (-1)^k$ for something that oscillates. The elements of this field don't live in the real numbers - they live on their own, as formal power series. Now, if you restricted this field to those series that *do* converge, I find it likely that you'll get all of $\mathbb{R}$; just pick a sequence $a_k$ as follows: Have $a_0$ agree with your target real number for the first digit, have $a_0+ta_1$ agree for the first two digits, and so on... and then, we'll have **many** different power series that go to the same real number! But then you can, for instance, set an equivalence relation, so that if they go to the same real number they're considered the same power series, and then we're just back to $\mathbb{R}$ again.

The question you really seem to want answered, though, is "Can we have a proper subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ that contains both $\mathbb{Q}$ and a specific transcendental $t$?" To which the answer is yes, and this field is denoted $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ (this is not your notation - it refers to the field of fractions of polynomials in $t$). We get this by forming the polynomials in $t$ (unlike the above power series, these can always be evaluated), and then making fractions with them; I described the explicit process for forming this field in an earlier revision, but it's really not that important here. Now, we do have $\mathbb{Q}(t) \subsetneq \mathbb{R}$ - and similarly for any finite set of transcendentals, we have $\mathbb{Q}(t_1,t_2,...,t_n)\subsetneq \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: As previously pointed out by Mr. Ted Shifrin, $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ is a rational formal power series in a fixed $t$ (because $t \in \mathbb{T}$ is a specific number, not a variable) so it is effectively a set of rational numbers and some real transcendental numbers.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'll edit my answer shortly.

Comment: @Pranasas In light of your comment on Asaf's answer, the answer to your question is "no" - we only need to pass to formal Laurent series to become a field. $\mathbb{Q}((t)) \subsetneq \mathbb{R}$ for any transcendental $t$.

Comment: This makes sense. Also for two different real transcendental numbers $t_1 \neq t_2$ maybe $\mathbb{Q}((t_1)) \cap \mathbb{Q}((t_2)) = \mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: Not necessarily - let's cheat and pick $t_2 = t_1^2$, for instance.  

Now that I think of it, the less I'm convinced $\mathbb{Q}[[t]]$ isn't $\mathbb{R}$. It's certainly true if you're only working with $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ (i.e., the rational functions in $\mathbb{R}$) - but if you're working with the formal power series, perhaps you could just pick a sequence of $a_k$ such that that infinite sum goes to any real number $r$...

Comment: If we think in terms of convergent power seris, surely we get all of $\Bbb{R}$! Let $a_0$ take care of the integer part. Pick $a_1$ in such a way that the integer part is unaffected, but the first decimal is now correct, fix the second decimal with $a_2$ et cetera.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen It appears to be the case that this very argument holds if we evaluate the power series at any $t \neq 0$ (i.e. not necessarity transcendental)?

Comment: @Pranasas: Agreed. Transcendentality is not essential at all in that argument.

Answer (score 2):

The union $\Bbb{Q\cup T}$ is not a ring, nor a field. The reason is that $\pi$ and $\frac{\sqrt2}{\pi}$ are in $\Bbb T$, but their product is not in $\Bbb{Q\cup T}$.

Comment: I think the OP intends a single fixed $t$. This is then rational formal power series in that fixed $t$. You're addressing the second question, of course.

Comment: @TedShifrin You are of course correct about the rational formal power series in fixed $t$. My question can also be understood as follows: if we introduce a real transcendental number $t$ into the field $\mathbb{Q}$, do we have to go all the way to $\mathbb{R}$ to have a field again?